# How to design the application to conform to the n-tier architecture? (Winform sample in .net with linq?)

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, n-tier-architecture

Rather a simple question. But the implications are vast.

Over the last few weeks I've been reading a lot of material about n-tier architecture and it's implementation in the .NET world. The problem is I couldn't find a relevant sample for Winforms with Linq (linq is the way to go for BLL right?).

How did you guys manage to grasp the n-tier concept? Books, articles, relevant samples etc.

**UPDATE:** I kind of wanted a sample app not just theory. I like to get into the specific implementation and then iterate the principles myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't technology specific but this is a very good book about n-tier architecture: [Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321127420)

Answer (score 1):

No, Linq2SQL in the BLL is not the way to go for n-tier architecture. I would use it in the DAL.

I would suggest you [start here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture), and keep reading. It is a simple concept, but there is a lot of literature out there to help understand it.

Try to understand the concepts first, without putting proprietary technologies into the mix. Once you understand the concepts, then think how to use things like Linq2SQL.

There are also about a billion posts on SO about this already, follow [this link](http://www.google.co.nz/search?num=100&hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=YUm&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial&q=n-tier+architecture+site%3Astackoverflow.com&meta=&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=) and cherry-pick the relevant bits from them